# Javascripts includes function is returning false in all conditions. Only else part is getting exectued

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Please help me figure out the mistake in below code. "includes" seem to return "false" only.

```
const arr = document.querySelector("#array");
const val = document.querySelector("#val");


const button1 = document.querySelector("#insert");
const button2 = document.querySelector("#enter");
let arr1=[];
button1.addEventListener("click",function(){
     arr1.push(Number(arr.value));
     console.log(arr1);
});

button2.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(val.value);

    if(arr1.includes(val.value)){
        console.log(`found at ${arr1.indexOf(val)}`);
    }else{
        console.log("not found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the values of `arr1` and `val`? Try to add a [mcve]

Comment: From where are you accessing `val.value` ?

Comment: I'd venture that `val.value` is a string. `arr1` contains only numbers. So `[1,2,3].includes("1")` evaluates to false, because it does not contain the string `"1"`, only the number 1

Comment: seing this `arr1.push(Number(arr.value));` the first thing that jumps to my mind is `NaN !== NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are have converted the input value to number

```
arr1.push(Number(arr.value));
```

so you cannot call it as string

change

```
arr1.includes(val.value)
```

to

```
arr1.includes(Number(val.value))
```

*by default the html input value returns a string, even if the input type is set to number*